# Classification Using Weka did not give any result for precision , Fmeasure and MCC

Tags: classification, precision, random-forest, weka, smote

I have a dataset. The dataset has some categorical values and some discrete value. My dataset is an imbalance dataset. I divide the dataset into 60% training data and 40% test data using `Resample` filter which is available in Weka. To make the dataset balanced I am using `SMOTE` technique. After that I used Random Forest to classify the dataset.

The result is

[image]

Now I can not understand what is the meaning of `?` in the result? Secondly, Why there is no value for False Positive and True Positive? Does that mean the dataset is still bias towards `No` class even after applying `SMOTE`?

Note: I applied SMOTE only on training data not in test data.

It would be helpful if someone clarify my doubts.

Answer (score 0):

That was asked on the Weka mailing list [before](https://list.waikato.ac.nz/hyperkitty/list/wekalist@list.waikato.ac.nz/thread/GKCAP6LNQORZU6766ATZQXZNJWMIUCEA/) (2019-07-26, *How can I explain the tag "?" in the performance of the model*). Here is Eibe's answer:

*It means the statistic could not be computed. For example, precision for class “High” cannot be computed because the classifier did not assign any instances to that class. This means the denominator in the calculation for precision is zero.*